# ¿Como puedo ocultar el contenido de un <li> sin que se visualice al presionar inspeccionar en un navegador?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Oculto un `<li style="display:none">` pero al hacer clic en inspeccionar en un navegador me permite ver su contenido. Quiero que no se visualice ese contenido al hacer clic en inspeccionar.

Comment: Podría ampliar un poco más el problema, porque podrías simplemente quitarlo del DOM con Javascript y no se vería al inspeccionar.

Comment: Lo que dices es lógico, el `<li>` dentro del dominio sigue existiendo, sólo que con un `css` distinto, si lo que buscas es que no se vea, tienes que usar javascript y simplemente removerlo del dominio, el tema, es que después no vas a poder agregarlo de nuevo (ocultar/mostrar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para esto podrias usar **Jquery** con la funcion: [remove](https://api.jquery.com/remove/)

**Mi html:**

```
<ul>
  <li class="list">Rusia</li>
  <li class="list">Mexico</li>
  <li class="list">España</li>
</ul>
```

**Eliminando los li :**

```
$('.list').each(function(){
$(this).remove()
});
```

Con esto eliminas los li por completo sin que se vea con el inspector del navegador.

**Nota.-**
En esta caso yo uso una clase css llamada **list**  para identificar y eliminarlos.. adapta este codigo a tus necesidades por id, clase, tag..

[Aqui verificalo](http://jsfiddle.net/zu0vxjrc/4/)

Espero te ayude !!